# how to clear the EXPECTED EXPRESSION error webservices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm writing this code for access webservice and getting an error `(EXPECTED EXPRESSION)`

```
-(IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender  //here I m getting the error(  (*expect expresion)))                          
{
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.2/mobileBill/login.ashx?username=%@&password =%@&simno=%@", username.text, password.text, @""];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some other function before `-(IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender` may not be closed. Try adding `}` before this function. And check whether all the functions have the correct opening and closing braces.